# Exception: Unable to generate etag from dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have an `IHttpHandler` in ASP.NET which serves some images. The handler sets the ETAG the following way:

```
context.Response.AddFileDependency(filename);                
context.Response.Cache.SetLastModifiedFromFileDependencies();
context.Response.Cache.SetETagFromFileDependencies();
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(999,0,0,0));
context.Response.Cache.SetSlidingExpiration(true);
context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);                
context.Response.Cache.VaryByParams["*"] = true;
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
context.Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(mi.Mi_filename);
context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

Sometimes a get an `System.Web.HttpException` Exception under IIS7 which says:

> Unable to generate etag from dependencies. One of the dependencies couldn't generate a unique id.

But I'm not able to reproduce the problem (I know that I can't test this with ASP.NET internal test web server). Has anybody a clue why this happens and what I can do to prevent this?

Comment: I get the same problem - did you ever figure this out?

Comment: After some research, I have established that this happens when the file dependency is a newly created file. I'm doing exactly the same thing as you - generating images. I generate a new image (write to hard disk), then I add the dependency and tell it to generate an etag from the dependency. If the file existed previously, it works fine, but if the file was generated as part of the current request I get the `System.Web.HttpException`. It's like the dependency manager thinks the file doesn't exist, even though it **definitely** does (I do a `File.Exists()` check first)

Answer (score 7):

I can't explain why this happens, but I found that making the thread sleep for a very short period of time allows the file dependency manager to **"get it's sh*t together"** and acknowledge that the newly generated file actually exists before trying to create an eTag from it.

```
...<code to generate "filename" goes here>...

// BUG: For some reason, even though the cache file has definitely been created at this stage, the file dependency manager
// seems to require a bit of time to "register" that the file exists before we add it to the list of dependencies.
// If we don't tell the thread to sleep, we will get an error when it generates the eTag (no idea why this happens - can't find anything on the web).
// If the cache file already existed when this request began, then there is no error.
Thread.Sleep(5);
context.Response.AddFileDependency(filename);                
context.Response.Cache.SetLastModifiedFromFileDependencies();
context.Response.Cache.SetETagFromFileDependencies();
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(999,0,0,0));
context.Response.Cache.SetSlidingExpiration(true);
context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);                
context.Response.Cache.VaryByParams["*"] = true;
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
context.Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(mi.Mi_filename);
context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

Comment: Yup, I have the same problem too... and blow me down this works. I don't like it that it works (with all due respect :) as I now wonder about the time(s) where 5ms doesn't quite cut it. At least for me it's to do with a cached resized image service, so a page refresh cures all. Would love to know what's really going on though

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown when `CacheDependency.GetUniqueID() == null`, so it should be possible to loop over a check for that.

```
var i = 0;
while (++i < 10)
{
    using (var cd = new CacheDependency(fi.FullName))
       if (cd.GetUniqueID() != null) break;
    Thread.Sleep(5*i);
}
if (i == 10)
   using (var cd = new CacheDependency(fi.FullName))
      if (cd.GetUniqueID() == null)
         throw new FileLoadException("Network drive out of sync with local view of it");
```